# making new tuple from list and dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to make a new tuple by splicing together a dictionary key and a numpy array turned into a list. However, I get this error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Here is my code

```
import numpy
import random


print(ly) 
{(1, 3): 2, (5, 2): 1, (10, 1): 0}

def myFun(layout):
    possibilities = numpy.zeros(shape=(4,2))
    possibilities[0] = [1, 0]
    possibilities[1] = [-1, 0]
    possibilities[2] = [0, 1]
    possibilities[3] = [0, -1]

    newLayout = tuple()
    for i in layout:
        randomDirection = random.choice( possibilities )
        newLayout = newLayout + layout.keys()[i] + list(randomDirection)
```

the interpreter shows this line

```
newLayout = newLayout + layout.keys()[i] + list(randomDirection)
```

as being problematic but I do not understand why

Comment: I'm assuming `ly` is being passed in as `layout`. The keys of `ly` are tuples, so `for i in layout`, means `i` is a `tuple` and you can't index `list` with a `tuple`. Note: `layout.keys()` in Py3 doesn't return a `list` anymore and would break even if `i` was an `int`.

Comment: you dict keys are tuple, and you are looping over them, so definitely the type of `i` is `tuple`

Comment: can you please share the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of in your code `newLayout = newLayout + layout.keys()[i] + list(randomDirection)`

Use following,
`newLayout = newLayout + layout[i] + list(randomDirection)`

will solve your problem

Comment: remove `.keys()` from statement

Comment: I tried your suggestion but get the following error "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple"